# FFmpeg libraries: Exactly constant segment duration for HLS

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

We are using FFmpeg libraries git-ee94362 libavformat v55.2.100.
Our purpose is to mux two streams (video and audio) into M3U8 playlist using HLS.
In addition, we want the duration of every TS segment file be exactly 3.0 sec (frame rate is 25 fps).

To reach it, we are trying to set several options and properties, namely: 
- segment_time
- keyint_min
- scenechange_threshold
- gop_size
- force_key_frames.

And our code looks as below:

```
AVCodecContext *codec_ctx = NULL;
AVFormatContext *ofmt_ctx = NULL;

int ret = 0, gopSize = (int)(3.0 * 25);   // 3 sec * 25 fps

// ofmt_ctx and codec_ctx initialization and filling are OK, but: 
codec_ctx->time_base.num = 1;
codec_ctx->time_base.den = 25 // fps

// It seems, that the following three lines have no effect without explisit setting of the "hls_time" property
codec_ctx->keyint_min = gopSize;       // in FFMpeg application, the corresponding option is "-keyint_min 3"
codec_ctx->scenechange_threshold = 0;  // in FFMpeg application, the corresponding option is "-sc_threshold 0"
codec_ctx->gop_size = gopSize;         // in FFMpeg application, the corresponding option is "-g 3"

ret = av_opt_set_double(ofmt_ctx, "hls_time", 3.0, AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);

// Any of the following lines causes "Option not found" error.
ret = av_opt_set(codec_ctx->priv_data, "profile", "main", AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
ret = av_opt_set(codec_ctx->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
ret = av_opt_get(ofmt_ctx, "segment_time",  AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN, &str);
ret = av_opt_set((ofmt_ctx, "segment_time", "3.0", AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
```

Anyway, the TS files durations are different, (~2-3 sec), and not EXACTLY 3.0 sec. 
Our question: What is the best way to solve the problem?

Andrey Mochenov.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you fixed this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem you are facing is probably that your **video file does not have key frames at fitting positions**. That is especially a problem if you just copy the streams from the input.

FFmpeg is depending on key frames to calculate when to "cut" a segment. Makes sense when you think about it. You can't just make a cut between two key frames, as each segment needs to be fully functional on its own. Now, one could argue that FFmpeg should just insert new key frames on its own, then, but that would be too use friendly, wouldn't it ;)

Thankfully, you can force key frames using FFmpeg. Either using a parameter or setting the flag yourself in code. You said that you already tried forcing key frames, but I assume that you did not do it correctly.

This test of mine produces quite good results. It is command line only, sorry, but you already seem to know how to apply command line params in code, so you should be fine.
Also note that I do not use the "hls_XXX" parameters because a) I honestly don't trust them and b) that way I figure it should also work for non-HLS streams.

```
ffmpeg -i inputFile.mov -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*10)" -strict -2 -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -f segment -segment_list_type m3u8 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_time 10.0 -segment_time_delta 0.1 -segment_list stream/test.m3u8 stream/test%02d.ts
```

You can look up how exactly the force_key_frames command works [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).

By now I implemented the above command in C++, with some additions. But without the "force_key_frames", as I set key frames manually during the transcoding process. Here is what I did:

```
AVDictionary* headerOptions(0);
av_dict_set(&headerOptions, "segment_format", "mpegts", 0);
av_dict_set(&headerOptions, "segment_list_type", "m3u8", 0);
av_dict_set(&headerOptions, "segment_list", _playlistFileName.c_str(), 0);
av_dict_set_int(&headerOptions, "segment_list_size", 0, 0);
av_dict_set(&headerOptions, "segment_time_delta", TO_STRING(1.00).c_str(), 0);
av_dict_set(&headerOptions, "segment_time", TO_STRING(_segmentDuration).c_str(), 0);
av_dict_set_int(&headerOptions, "reference_stream", _videoStream->index, 0);
av_dict_set(&headerOptions, "segment_list_flags", "cache+live", 0);
avformat_write_header(_formatContext, &headerOptions);
```

And here is the resulting m3u8:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXTINF:10.083333,
test00.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
test01.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
test02.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
test03.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
test04.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
test05.ts
#EXTINF:0.083333,
test06.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

It is not perfect (first part is a little bit off somehow), but I am convinced you won't get better results than that.

Of course, the best option would be to make sure your input files always have correct key frames when just copying the streams, but sometimes you have no control over what files you get.

**Side Note**

When you are using FFmpeg in code, always try what you are doing in code using the cli ffmpeg command first. If you can get it to work that way, you at least know what parameters to set in code. And if it works using the command line tool, you know it must be possible in code somehow ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try achieving 3 seconds segments (approximately) duration by modifying ffmpeg. As @theSHEEP pointed ffmpeg waits for I frame to arrive before making a cut. You can change this behavior of ffmpeg by forcing it to make cut at "your time" than waiting for I frame.

```
    ffmpeg/libavformat/segment.c, 
     795 static int seg_write_packet(AVFormatContext *s, AVPacket *pkt)

     835     if (pkt->stream_index == seg->reference_stream_index &&
     836         pkt->flags & AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY &&
     837         seg->segment_frame_count > 0 &&
     838         (seg->cut_pending || seg->frame_count >= start_frame ||
     839          (pkt->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE &&
     840           av_compare_ts(pkt->pts, st->time_base,
     841                         end_pts-seg->time_delta, AV_TIME_BASE_Q) >= 0)))
```

I would change line 835 to 841 to fit my requirement. (Comment line number 836 and try, and remember FFMPEG is LGPL)

HLS IETF draft version recommends:

> The server SHOULD attempt to divide the source media at points that
>   support effective decode of individual Media Segments, e.g. on packet
>   and key frame boundaries

I will read it as recommendation than requirement. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its not very good to force a cut on a place that doesn't have an I frame because if only the frames in that particular segment need to be decoded they will be filled with grey boxes. There is simply not enough data to decode a full frame properly.

The best way would be to encode a sequence first with:

```
AVCodecContext *enc_ctx;
...
av_opt_set_int(enc_ctx, "sc_threshold", sc_threshold, 0);
enc_ctx->gop_size = 3 * 25;
av_opt_set_int(enc_ctx, "keyint_min", min_keyint, 0);
```

Later on, once your encoding is complete you can separately mux the file for HLS or do it while encoding. In my particular use case I was doing it after the entire encoding cycle was complete. Code from @TheSHEEEP helped with this, but the options he used weren't the ones I needed.

```
size_t f = output_filename.find_last_of(".");
string ofn = output_filename.substr(0, f);
ofn.append(".m3u8");
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, "hls", ofn.c_str());

AVDictionary* headerOptions = NULL;
av_dict_set(&headerOptions, "hls_segment_type", "mpegts", 0);
av_dict_set(&headerOptions, "hls_playlist_type", "event", 0);
av_dict_set_int(&headerOptions, "hls_list_size", 0, 0);
av_dict_set(&headerOptions, "segment_time_delta", "1.0", 0);
av_dict_set(&headerOptions, "hls_flags", "append_list", 0);

ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, &headerOptions);
```

Where **ofmt_ctx** is output AVFormatContext. The output file is as same as in the post from @TheSHEEEP.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem making an HLS streaming from images captured with a camera and to me, the best results were obtained using these options (to create segments of 5 secs):

```
    AVDictionary *header_op(0);
    // type
    av_dict_set(&header_op, "hls_segment_type", "mpegts", 0);
    // auto delete old segments
    av_dict_set(&header_op, "hls_flags", "delete_segments", 0);
    // list type
    av_dict_set(&header_op, "segment_list_type", "m3u8", 0);
    // playlist size
    av_dict_set_int(&header_op, "hls_list_size", 5, 0);
    // segment time accuracy
    av_dict_set(&header_op, "segment_time_delta", "1.00", 0);
    // ~max time for each segment
    av_dict_set(&header_op, "hls_time", "5.0", 0);
    // enforce hls_time
    av_dict_set(&header_op, "hls_flags", "split_by_time", 0);

    av_dict_set_int(&header_op, "reference_stream", m_stream->index, 0);
    av_dict_set(&header_op, "segment_list_flags", "cache+live", 0);

    if (avformat_write_header(m_fmt_ctx, &header_op))
        // Error...
```

The trick are in the `hls_time` and `split_by_time` options as is [explained here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-6)

The results are pretty near to the 5 secs:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:4
#EXTINF:5.033333,
example4.ts
#EXTINF:4.966667,
example5.ts
#EXTINF:5.000000,
example6.ts
#EXTINF:5.100000,
example7.ts
#EXTINF:0.200000,
example8.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

The last segment was interrupted before finishing.